# npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED - InCoder

Tags: npm, npm-package

npm install ora
npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/
meow: A0130000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher op
eration failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciph
ercommon_gcm.c:320:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\yash\AppData\Local
\npm-cache_logs\2023-07-27T16_50_16_038Z-debug-0.log

i have been getting this error when i install nay npm package. i have tried reinstalling node js but i'm still getting this error.

anybody will help me to solve this error.